# Is really that "Breath Stops when Thought Stops"

Tags: meditation-mindfulness, meditation

Is Body - Breath - Mind are connected to each other, and Thinking process really need oxygen to operate. When I sit for meditation i feel my breath is stop (Gap) and thought slows down, but for very minimum time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a bad translation. Alternative ways to say it:

Breath Gradually Ceases when Thought Gradually Ceases
Breath Gradually Stills when Thought Gradually Stills
Breath Quietens when Thought Quietens
Breath Calms Down when Thought Calms Down

Consider [SN 36.11](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn36/sn36.011.nypo.html):

> "I have taught, monk, **the gradual cessation** of conditioned phenomena. [...] Having attained the second absorption, thought-conception and discursive thinking has ceased. [...] Having attained the fourth absorption, inhalation and exhalation have ceased.
>
> "I have further taught, monk, **the gradual stilling** of conditioned phenomena. [...] Having attained the second absorption, thought-conception and discursive thinking been  stilled. [...] Having attained the fourth absorption, inhalation and exhalation have been stilled.
>
> "There are, monk, these six **quietenings** (or calmings). [...] Having attained the second absorption, thought-conception and discursive thinking are quietened. [...] Having attained the fourth absorption, inhalation and exhalation is quietened.

Comment: Thank you @Andrei Volkov. Now I am understanding.. Now my question is   "How to be Completely aware in each and every moment"...even Working, Walking, Talking.. can "Continuous Breath Awareness" is a Answer??

Comment: Yes, you got it :)

Comment: Ok.. Its means Only awareness.. not contemplation .. not concentration..

Answer (score 1):

Mental Fabrications is associated with sensations, hence will not stop until sensations stop. There are ways to stop thoughts is to develop Nirodha Samapatti or realise Nirvana by other means. When you have Nirvana as object only will your thinking stop. Verbal fabrication which is Thinking and Pondering will stop in the second Jhana.

When breathing stops your bodily fabrications have stopped. But when thoughts arise new fabrications arise which might have bodily impact hence breathing start again.

The there is a gap or breathing stops you have to contemplate the sensations you experience in the upper lip or even the whole body. See: [LECTURE FOUR: MASTERING THE VEDANA](http://www.dhammatalks.net/Books3/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Anapanasati_Mindfulness_with_Breathing.htm#LECTURE%20FOUR) by [ANAPANASATI - MINDFULNESS WITH BREATHING Unveiling the Secrets of Life: a Manual for Serious Beginners](http://www.dhammatalks.net/Books3/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Anapanasati_Mindfulness_with_Breathing.htm). When the breath is there look at the flow and touch of the breath. When it is not the sensations on the last point the breath touched. (2nd Tetrads)

Do not get alarmed if your breath stops for a long duration but this should not be forced.

[image]

Source: [Anapanasati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anapanasati)

Comment: Thank you @Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena. But what is a goal of meditation. Increasing the GAP (When breath stops)?. That's lead to a Present moment, Absorbing in Moment??. or analyzing??.. When the awareness is aware of awareness?? please guide me..

Comment: Great you felt it was useful. I feel this might need to be posted as a new question, as if I answer it here this my answer will not be for your original question.

Comment: I think I can add it here as you mentioned gap in the original question.

Comment: Ok. @Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena

Comment: I noticed you accepted my answer but not unvoted. Upvote is to signal something is useful or giving your endorsement to the answer / question. So wondering if I have missed something or there is gap between what you expected out of the answer than what I gave?

Comment: Respected @Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena sir, Thank you for your valuable replay. But I am a new user in Stack Overflow and unless and until I earn total 15 reputation my Vote doesn't count. My vote publicly display after 15 reputation.

Comment: I did not know that. Anyway just wanted to see if there was a fault or shortfall in my part.

Comment: No sir, there is no fault in your side, as per your suggestion I posted new question and I am waiting for your answer. Thank you once again.